# Best way to add computed property in typescript after API call based on object's values

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to add a computed property in the objects after retrieved from all my services.

For example, I have a call that returns this: `Player[]`

```
[
   {id: 123, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', average: .345, rank: 6 },
   {id: 124, firstName: 'Jeremey', lastName: 'Deng', average: .245, rank: 24 },
];
```

Now these Player objects are in the same format when called by other APIs in other services.  What I would like to do is create properties in these objects such as:

```
 {id: 123, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', average: .345, rank: 6, allStar: true }
```

allStar is `true` IF average is `> .333` AND `rank < 10`.

Basically where should this logic liveif I need to execute for any call that returns player objects? Ideally this logic should live in 1 place instead of repeating it obviously.

Comment: Make a Player class and write an accessor? Do it at the transport boundary in the service? What are your constraints, what have you considered?

Comment: Only way I'm aware of adding a map function to all responses that return player objects but trying to avoid that as that doesn't seem efficient.

Comment: Is it your own API or a 3rd party that you can't edit? Because I would expect this type of thing to be put on the API side

Comment: Its repetieive logic that I will have to add to numerous APIs.  It is a problem hence the question.

Comment: Also this is an example - there are many things I would like to add.  Main question is how do we acheieve this without adding repepetive logic in several places.

Comment: @jonrsharpe What exactly do you mean by transport boundary

Answer (score -2):

you should have a getPlayers() function in your Players service. That would be a good place to put it.